# How to I include a class in a ruby lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file names usa_epay.rb in the lib directory of my rails application with a class declared like this

```
require 'base64'
require 'uri'
require 'rubygems'
require 'cgi'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'digest/md5'
require 'digest/sha1'

Usaepay_version = "1.0.0"

class UmTransaction
```

How do i include it in my rails application so i can do

```
UmTransaction.new
```

any ideas

This is a rails 2 application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add include your class like this **include_class 'include_path_to_your_class_file'**

You may even add something  in your environments/development/your_file.yml file like

```
help:

class: "ProjectName::Main::UserAction::HelpHandler"**
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write a class, even one that has nothing to do with ActiveRecord you can store it in the `app/model` directory then it will be included in the environment.

Comment: lets say i have an order model and now a usa_epay model  how in the order.rb do i include the usa_epay